# how to subtract two array in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

i'm new for mulesoft development, i want to subtract two array in dataweave .
the two array are below

```
var array1 = [ {
    "FF15974433790786634518": 2 },
    {"FF15974433790786634519": 2  },
    { "FF15974433790786634520": 1 }   ]
   
var array2 = [ {"FF15974433790786634518": 1 },
  {"FF15974433790786634519": 2  },
  { "FF15974433790786634520": 1 }   ]
```

i want to get this result:

```
 [ {"FF15974433790786634518": 1 },
  {"FF15974433790786634519": 0  },
  { "FF15974433790786634520": 0 }  ]
```

May i know how to write in dataweave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this with one of them being below: Iterating over the first array, subsequently on each object within the array and then using the key from the object (which is the alphanumeric string) , build the target/desired object structure by subtracting the values for the keys stored in each of these arrays

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var array1 = [ 
    {"FF15974433790786634518": 2},
    {"FF15974433790786634519": 2},
    { "FF15974433790786634520": 1}   
    ]
   
var array2 = [ {"FF15974433790786634518": 1 },
  {"FF15974433790786634519": 2  },
  { "FF15974433790786634520": 1 }   ]


---
(array1 map {
    temp: $ mapObject {
        ($$):(array1[($$)][0] - array2[($$)][0])
    }
}.temp)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "FF15974433790786634518": 1
  },
  {
    "FF15974433790786634519": 0
  },
  {
    "FF15974433790786634520": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i found i can use array1-array2 to get the variance item

Comment: array1 - array2 will give you elements of array1 that are common with array2. Anything extra in array2 will be omitted from the final result while if there are extra elements in array1, they will be part of the final result.

Comment: sorry it should be array1 -- array2

Comment: Please do accept the answer in case you find it serves your purpose. @maomifadacai